How can I effectively log my lightning component with LWS and LWR
I am developing a custom LWR experience site and trying to console.log various things in my javascript controllers, but nothing valuable is being included.
I am familiar with JSON.serialize / JSON.parse trick while logging to get around proxy objects hiding what you're logging, but even doing this I am still unable to see the actual data.
For example, I have a custom event handler that receives a custom event from a component and logs it.
handleTagChange(event) {
    console.log('handle tag change', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event)));
    console.log('value', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)));
}

The first log prints
{isTrusted: false, composed: false}
The Second log prints
{value: 'aHUO9000000AyqwOAC', record: {…}, name: 'CCAC', objectType: 'Tag__c'}
I would expect the first log to show the detail, but it does not.
I have disabled lightning web security in both my org and in my experience


How can I effectively log everything that's included on a POJO without having to know what properties exist beforehand to access them?

In LWR with LWS disabled there is no need to wrap what you are logging with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()))
Simply logging console.log(POJO) will log what you are expecting to see
handleTagChange(event) {
    console.log('no manipulation', event);
}

Old habits die I hard I guess when Salesforce decided to Proxy wrap everything
